# Resuelto ngx-cookie-service no se setea cookie hasta refrescar

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, setcookie, ngx

Versión 13.3.11 de **Angular**.

versión 13.12.1 de **ngx-cookie-service**.

Tengo un login en Angular, donde al loguearme con exito obtengo un objeto con datos del usuario y entre ellos un "**Token**", en front en cuanto recibo ese objeto lo seteo en una cookie:

```
cookieService.set("current_user", "exampleData", { path: "/admin", sameSite: "Lax" });
```

el inconveniente que noto es que a la par que seteo la cookie, me desplazo con el router al dashboard, pero en mi consola aún no esta la cookie, sino que refresco el sitio de forma manual con un (F5) y se agrega.

Se supone que al setearla debería de agregarse en la consola no? me faltará algo más que se me este pasando en si tome el ejemplo de la documentación, la única diferencia es que seteo una ruta de **path** y en la docu toma default un **"/"**.

Ejemplo de la documentación: [Documentación ngx-cookie-service](https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service)

```
cookieService.set('test', 'Hello World', {expires: 2, sameSite: 'Lax'});
```

**Actualización:**

pude resolverlo, a raíz de otra pregunta que estuve analizando y al parecer encontré una solución, igual dejaré la pregunta aquí:

[Angular 9 - ngx-cookie-service troubles with path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63674233/angular-9-ngx-cookie-service-troubles-with-path/76296925#76296925)